# Scala: return based on value of int expression

Tags: scala

I'm trying to calculate the time from various dates since a specific period start date. Calculating the dates since was fine and easy, but I also want the function to return -1 if the dates between them is negative. I'm not sure a clean way to do this? 
I've got:

```
def getTimeBetween(date1: String, date2: String, format: String, dtype: String): Int = {
  dtype match {
    case "fixed" => {
      if (date1 == null) throw new Exception("Specify date1")
      else Days.daysBetween(date2, date1).getDays()
    }
    case _ => throw new Exception("Enter a valid type")
  }
}
```

I'm pretty new to Scala so I don't know all the syntax well yet. I'm more used to Java/C++, so I thought next if/else statements would work but I've realized it's not the way to go.

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, `type` is a keyword in scala so you cannot use it as a variable. Secondly, can you use a library like `joda.time` or are you restricted to primitive types?

Comment: That's not exactly what i named everything. I'm doing this as an intern and didn't want to put my actual code up. I am using the joda.time library

Comment: Are date1 and date2 actually Strings here or do you have them as `DateTime` types?

Comment: I'm using primitive types because this is with hadoop. I can get the days between just fine. I just pass in the date string and the format of the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A definite improvement would be to not throw runtime exceptions and instead rely on a standard Scala construct, `Try` comes to mind here.

```
import scala.util.{ Success, Failure, Try }

import org.joda.time.Days

def getTimeBetween(date1: String, date2: String, format: String, dtype: String): Try[Int] = {
  dtype match {
    case "fixed" => {
      Try(Days.daysBetween(date2, date1).getDays) match {
        case Success(days) if days >= 0 => Success(days)
        case Success(_) => Success(-1)
        case Failure(t) => Failure(t)
      }
    }
    case _ => Failure(new IllegalArgumentException)
  }
}
```

This method will return `Success(#days)` with the number of days between if they're positive, or `Success(-1)` if they're negative.

The `Try` wrapper around the `daysBetween` function will catch any exceptions that might be thrown during parsing, such as illegal formats or `null` values in the parameters. Any runtime exception will result in a `Failure(t)` with `t` being the exception caught.

There's a lot of other ways to approach this, like the `Either` type, or using `Option` and the `scala.util.catching` function.

**Edit**:

Since you left it out of your example I did also, but for the `daysBetween` method to compile you'll need to parse the strings into DateTime objects, using something like `DateTime.parse(date1)` etc.

Comment: Given that date1 and date2 are strings, isn't some explicit conversion necessary?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was trying various things with match but couldn't find something like Try/Success/Failure. My only question though is when returning values, can I just be like `if days >= 0 => days` or does returning `Success(days)` have any extra value?

Comment: Notice the return type of the method, it's `Try[Int]`. So you can't return just `days` since that is an integer.

Comment: Yeah but if I just keep the return type as Int, is there anything inherently wrong with that? Does returning Try[Int] have any extra value?

Comment: Yes, since any exceptions get caught in the `Failure` type, instead of being thrown at runtime. `Failure` and `Success` extend Try, so to use them you must return a `Try[T]` in your method. Read some more over here:
http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your method returns a negative integer and you want it to return -1 instead of all negative values you could simply put it in an auxilary variable and check

```
val res = Days.daysBetween(date2, date1).getDays()
if (res <0) -1 else res
```

A more compact (and argueably less clear method) only for Int would be using max

```
Days.daysBetween(date2, date1).getDays().max(-1)
```